# Installing Ubuntu on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac

I have a MacBook Air, 13-inch, Mid 2011, running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5. I intend to have a dual boot setup with Ubuntu 13. So I did some googling and found the some instructions (http://nosemaj.org/dual-boot-mac-linux). However, when I tried to resize the OSX partition, I found no option in Disk Utility to do that. Is it because the author was running a different version of OS X?

Comment: @nerdwaller thanks for the link. My question is answered.

Comment: Moved that to an answer since it helped.  In the future, please be a bit more clear in what you are asking, suggesting what version of OSX, unless they state it, would be mostly conjecture as you couldn't find it in the article.  Instead it may be better to ask "How would I change the partition size in OSX 10.x?  I tried x but was unable to find the option I expected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSX Disk Utility hasn't really changed much in years, outside of a few features (new format handling, etc.) -  it's basically the same now as it was around 8 yrs ago.

There isn't really a "change size" button, instead it's a slider:

[image]

[moved to an answer]